# XAMPP 7.2.13 php -ext-int extension error

Tags: php, xampp, php-extension

I am trying to run a basic cake 3.7 application, however after I create a new project I get a You must enable the intl extension to use CakePHP. According to CakePHP, XAMPP comes with intl extension it just needs to to be enabled via php.ini. I enabled the extension and restarted the server and it did not work. I look inside my extensions directory `xamppfiles/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20170718` and could not find the required extension. My question is how do install and enable this extension to satisfy the requirement error?

Answer (score 0):

I've just double-checked and indeed Xampp is coming with php_intl.dll (in your /php/ext folder).

You can enable this extension easily in your php.ini file:

1. Edit php.ini and remove `;` on this line `;extension=php_intl.dll`
2. Restart Xampp

Comment: I have tried this enabling the extension through the php.ini file as stated in above. Is there a way to tell if I'm using XAMPP php or my system's php?

Comment: Definitely: you can easily check which php.ini is in use by calling phpinfo()

Comment: Be careful with Xampp 7.2 packages. I downloaded the portable version of it and found out that ALL extensions in php.ini file have wrong names: they did not have the prefix php_ and the suffix .dll in their names.